# Running only files containing `ts-check` comment on `tsc` cli command

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using Typescript type checking from VSCode thru the `ts-check` comment on those file which I want to check. It works perfectly!

[image: tscheck]

Now I'd like to use the `tsc` cli command to check the same files I added `ts-check` comment.

**Is that possible using only `tsc`?**

If I use the following command **all files** are validated and I'm not willing to add only those which must be validated on jsconfig/tsconfig.

```
npx tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit --target ES5 src/**/*.js
```

Which are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check only .js files with `// @ts-check`, you can drop `--checkJs` argument from `tsc` CLI, as described in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html):

> You can skip checking some files by adding a // @ts-nocheck comment to them; conversely, you can choose to **check only a few .js files** by **adding a // @ts-check comment** to them **without setting --checkJs**.